# WPF Enter full screen on mediaElement double clicked does not react always

Tags: wpf, fullscreen, double-click

I've been searching the easy way to make my window (which contains only a mediaElement) go full screen when it's double clicked. Since I'm new to WPF/C# I did it the way it was suggested [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event). It works, but it doesn't react always and sometimes I even have to click more than 3 times in row to get it into full screen or restored.

Here is the event handler:

```
 private void mediaElement1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2 && fullscreen==false)
        {
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else if (e.ClickCount == 2 && fullscreen == true)
        {

            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;

    }
```

Comment: Two tips: 1. Put a trace point or `Debug.WriteLine(...)` call in the event handler to see if it gets called each time you do your double click. 2. You don't need the explicit boolean comparisons within your conditional statements, you can just do `if (... && !fullscreen)` and `if (... && fullscreen)`.

Comment: I have to click like a maniac in order to make it execute the handler. It gets executed corectly every time it enters in it, but the problem is why it doesn't enter it every time I click twice. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I solved the problem other way. Using [this](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1894-wpf-full-screen-view-for-media-element.aspx) solution.

Answer (score 4):

The following code demonstrate how to make the window fullscreen by double clicking in the media element. Just change "path_to_file" for the appropriated path the file in the DemoWindow.xaml.cs

### Importart: The Source property from MediaElement must be set to enable the MouseLeftButtonUp event. Otherwise the event handler is not called.

---

**DemoWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="FullscreenDemo.DemoWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DemoWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                      MouseLeftButtonUp="MediaPlayer_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**DemoWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace FullscreenDemo
{
    public partial class DemoWindow : Window
    {
        private bool fullscreen = false;
        private DispatcherTimer DoubleClickTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public DemoWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleClickTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetDoubleClickTime());
            DoubleClickTimer.Tick += (s, e) => DoubleClickTimer.Stop();

            var path = @"path_to_file";
            MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(path);
        }

        private void MediaPlayer_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!DoubleClickTimer.IsEnabled)
            {
                DoubleClickTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!fullscreen)
                {
                    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                }

                fullscreen = !fullscreen;
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetDoubleClickTime();
    }
}
```

---

**Reference**

https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/full-screen-view-for-media-element-in-wpf/

Answer (score -4):

Use this:

```
private void mediaElement1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickCount == 2 && fullscreen==false)
            {
                this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    fullscreen == true;
            }
            else if (e.ClickCount == 2 && fullscreen == true)
            {

                this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    fullscreen == false;
            }

        }
```

Its the easiest way !